# Specific issue in js based 2d game

Tags: javascript, this

I make a 2d game using JavaScript (i know, there are better languages dedicated to 2d games, but now i am in js).  Already there are a 2d map 10x10, inserting player's and enemy's image, walking using arrow keys and i have issue with fight system. This is constructor where it think is mistake

```
function Character(n,h1,so,sa,x,y,t)  
{
this.name=n;
this.hpmax=h1;
this.hp=800;
this.sila_obrony=so; //defence
this.sila_ataku=sa; //attack
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.type=t; //player(pl), golem(gl), troll(tr), cyklop(ck), procarz(pr), boss(bs)

this.atak = function(enemy)
{
  if(((enemy.x==this.x)||(enemy.x==this.x-1)||(enemy.x==this.x+1))&&
  ((enemy.y==this.y)||(enemy.y==this.y-1)||(enemy.y==this.y+1)))    
  {
    alert('<span style="color:red">'+this.name+" Atakuje "+enemy.name+"</span><br>");
    var min = this.sila_ataku-(this.sila_ataku/5);
    var max = this.sila_ataku+(this.sila_ataku/5);
    var damage=Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min-enemy.sila_obrony;    
    enemy.hp-=damage;
    alert(enemy.hp);
  }else 
  {
    alert("You are not around");
    alert("Player's x: "+this.x+" Player's y: "+this.y+" Enemy's x: "+enemy.x+" Enemy's y: "+enemy.y);
  }
}

this.insert = function() //inserting character on 2d map
{
  var character = document.createElement("img");

  if(typeof this.exp !== 'undefined') character.className = "character"; //only player has exp field
  else character.className = "enemy";

  character.addEventListener('click', function() {Player.atak(this);}, false);
  character.style.left = this.x*60+"px"; //this code counts how move character's image on map
  character.style.top = this.y*50-50+"px";
  if (this.type=="pl") {character.src="img/character.png"; character.id = "pl";}
  if (this.type=="gl") {character.src="img/golem.png"; character.id = "gl";}
  if (this.type=="tr") {character.src="img/troll.png"; character.id = "tr";}
  if (this.type=="ck") {character.src="img/cyklop.png"; character.id = "ck";}
  if (this.type=="pr") {character.src="img/procarz.png"; character.id = "pr";}
  if (this.type=="bs") {character.src="img/boss.png"; character.id = "bs";}

  document.getElementById("map").appendChild(character);
}
}
```

And this is what i receive
[after onClick on enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eosve.jpg)

I expected successful fight but there is alert "You are not around" and enemy's coords from cosmos. Furthermore when i click on myself i have alert "Player's x: 2 Player's y: 2 Enemy's x: 135 Enemy's y: 258",but in that situation player and enemy are the same object.

I suppose than solution is 'just around the corner' but i can find it on my own.

I will be grateful if someone will suss out why there are strange x a y values.

Comment: `i know, there are better languages dedicated to 2d games, but now i am in js` -> i bet the productivity in js is actually much higher ( at least for smaller games ). Not to note WebVR and other cool stuff...